# Bootstrap Form Input Fields look odd

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been creating a multistep form with three tabs. And I am having problems with the bootstrap styling of the input fields.

This is what it currently looks like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NT6e.jpg):
[image]

As you can see, the input fields are not what you would get in bootstrap. When you input into them it makes the box bigger (shown in Site Name).

Below is the code that I have tried. And is reproducible.

Here is my GitHub where you can also see the code. (not promoting, just there to show all of the code).

```css
.top-bar{

    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    background-color: #006bff;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
.phone,.logout{
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.phone:hover,.logout:hover{
    color: #F0C330;
    transition:0.5s;
}
body{
    background-color: #A6C7F0!important;
}
.logo{
    padding:20px;
}
.container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.container form{    
    background-color: #EEF1F4 !important;            /*Change Size of Box*/
    width: 900px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
} 
.box{
    width: 800px;
}
.container table {
    background-color: #EEF1F4 !important;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.link-right{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.suggestions{
    width:98.5%;
    height:125px;
    position: relative;
    bottom:17px;
}
.container h1{
    color: #0B2D58;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="...">
    <title><?= $data['title'] ?? '' ?></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Form Start -->
        <form class="row g-3" id="surveyForm" action="<?= $data['action'] ?>" method="post">

            <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
            <!-- Tab 1 Start -->
                <h1>Contact & Site Details</h1>
                <!-- Row 1 Start -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <label for="site_name" class="form-label">Site Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="site_name" name="site_name"  placeholder="Enter Site Name" oninput="this.className = ''" required><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label for="poNum" class="form-label">PO Number*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="poNum" name="poNum"  placeholder="Enter PO Number" oninput="this.className = ''" required><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label for="customer_name" class="form-label">Contact Name*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customer_name" name="customer_name"  placeholder="Enter Contact Name" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <label for="customer_email" class="form-label">Email Address*</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="customer_email" name="customer_email"  placeholder="Enter Email" oninput="this.className = ''" required><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-4">
                        <label for="customer_mobile" class="form-label">Contact Number*</label>
                        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="customer_mobile" name="customer_mobile"  placeholder="Enter Contact Number" oninput="this.className = ''" required> <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-8">
                        <label for="street1" class="form-label">Address*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street1" name="street1"  placeholder="Address" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label for="city" class="form-label">City/Town*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="city" placeholder="City/Town" oninput="this.className = ''" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <label for="county" class="form-label">County*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="county" name="county"  oninput="this.className = ''" placeholder="County">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label for="postcode" class="form-label">Postcode*</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" name="postcode"  placeholder="Postcode" oninput="this.className = ''" required> <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Row 1 End -->
            
        </form> <!--Form End -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I cannot edit the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are clearing all bootstrap classes on input on all fields.

`oninput="this.className = ''"` - Remove this from all inputs, and your form will look as it is supposed to.

But, why do you have that in the first place, what is the objective?

Comment: This is used for the tabs. I am unsure why it is used, but i will see if it affects the code if its not on it

Comment: Ignore what i said previously, this works...